# XGBoost for Python: plot importance

Tags: python, matplotlib, xgboost

following the instructions from 
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html

after building my model, i tried on Jupyter (using Mac OS X, Chrome browser)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.style.use('ggplot') 
xgb.plot_importance(bst) 
xgb.plot_tree(bst, num_trees=2) 
xgb.to_graphviz(bst, num_trees=2)
```

but i have some problems:
the to_graphviz does return me a plot, but its too big, and i can't see it whole. Its cut on the right side

the first two commands (if i put a # in front of the last line) don't show any plot at all. 
is there something like `a.show()` missing ?

Instead i get the following output

> "matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x12f0ee7d0" (between <>)

can anyone help ? thank you

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you should add this: `plt.show()`
.